# How to create an object in factory_girl which validates that it has at least one associated object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

There is the following code:

```
  let!(:beauty_salon_service) { create(:beauty_salon_service) }
  let!(:beauty_salon_employee) { build(:beauty_salon_employee, 
                                       business: beauty_salon_service.beauty_salon_category.business) }
  before do
    beauty_salon_employee.beauty_salon_employee_services.build(beauty_salon_service: beauty_salon_service)
    beauty_salon_employee.save!
  end
```

Two conditions:

1. beauty_salon_service and beauty_salon_employee must point to the
   same business (you can see it);
2. beauty_salon_employee must have not
       blank has_many through association beauty_salon_employee_services
       (validate presence);

My FactoryGirl code doesn't work - "Validation failed: Beauty salon employee services can't be blank". How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`let!` happens before `before`, so the employee is created without a service (you probably knew that). To fix your immediate problem you need to provide the service when the employee is created.

You can initialize a many-to-many relationship when you create an object in factory_girl (or in ActiveRecord, for that matter) like this:

```
let!(:beauty_salon_employee) do
  build :beauty_salon_employee,
    business: beauty_salon_service.beauty_salon_category.business,
    beauty_salon_employee_services: [beauty_salon_service]
end
```

Although possibly what you really want to do is to create the BeautySalonService in the BeautySalonFactory. [The factory_girl documentation for associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) gives an example of how to fill a one-to-many association in a callback:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  # post factory with a `belongs_to` association for the user
  factory :post do
    title "Through the Looking Glass"
    user
  end

  # user factory without associated posts
  factory :user do
    name "John Doe"

    # user_with_posts will create post data after the user has been created
    factory :user_with_posts do
      # posts_count is declared as a transient attribute and available in
      # attributes on the factory, as well as the callback via the evaluator
      ignore do
        posts_count 5
      end

      # the after(:create) yields two values; the user instance itself and the
      # evaluator, which stores all values from the factory, including transient
      # attributes; `create_list`'s second argument is the number of records
      # to create and we make sure the user is associated properly to the post
      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        create_list(:post, evaluator.posts_count, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In your case you'll need to use `before_create` rather than `after_create` to satisfy your validation.